# Express site will not launch

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, express, web

I have used node/Express framework before and I am trying to launch an old webApp that I have used before. Whenever I type ./bin/www nothing happens.. Usually it would say "listening on port 3000" but absolutely nothing happens. I go to the site and there is no connection. No error messages or anything. Does anyone know why this might be happening? I have done it before on another Ubuntu operating system and I am now just trying to launch it on Xubuntu

I am also setting the debug to ./bin/www by inputting:
DEBUG = ./bin/www

EDIT: Found the problem... Apparently I had to install node-legacy instead

Comment: Are you calling node (or nodemon etc.) e.g. 'node bin/www' ?

Comment: Yes I am. And I am also setting the debug to ./bin/www.

Comment: Can you make new app and run it to see if that's working. ..

Comment: Might be a silly question, however is the port in your www file set to 3000. When you run node bin/www it will usually show nothing until you start making requests. If the port is wrong then you'll never get to the app to know